# How can print values form inside class function in php

Tags: php, debugging

I have simple php page that calls php object method like this:
this is the HTML page that build the html view

```
$queryManager = new  QueryManager();
$result = $queryManager->GetCreatedCars($userId);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
...blah blah ....
}

and this is how the GetCreatedCars looks
public function GetCreatedCars($user_fb_id)
    {
        $bcon  = $this->ConnectToDb();
        $myStr = "SELECT * FROM ...blah blah .....";

            echo "$myStr <br>"; <----THIS I WANT TO PRINT TO HTML VIEW 
                $result = mysql_query($SqlStr);
        if(!$result)
            die('Could select db: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }
```

now i like to print to page the $myStr just for debug ,but the dosn't prints any thing i   can print only what i have in the view php file where i call GetCreatedCars method

Comment: `$myStr = "SELECT * FROM ...blah blah .....";
echo($myStr);`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your method gets called? Please post a minimal testcase. Does $this->ConnectToDb terminate the program (perhaps the method does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `echo ...;` to `die(...);`. This way, if the method gets called correctly, the page will "die" and show that message at the bottom.